# can I use multiprocessing with the customer Tweepy StreamListner class?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, tweepy

thanks in advance and please allow my ignorance on the multiprocessing/threading area. I am very new to this...

Currently, I succeed to get all tweets containing the word 'Yolo' and store it to my local DB(SQLite way).

Now, I am thinking of using SQS.

Let's say

1) I am listening to all random Tweets from twitter Server
2) If the current tweet(status) is what I want, then I want to store this into DB. This is What function on_status(status) is doing.

2-1) Let's say(not on my code but..) I successfully made temp_array which should contain every 100 tweets(containing 'yolo') in Shared Memory(heard I have to use this if I want to use multi-processor to work)

3) while def on_status is doing its job, I want to use separate processor(multiprocessing) to send those cumulated 100 tweets (in temp_array at shared memory) by using function name send_to_sqs().

For steps 2) and 3), I want to use two different processors.

But I realized it is not easy(for me) since function send_to_sqs() and update_tweet_bundle() and table.insert(tweet_dict) is all working in CLASS !(not at main).

Can someone please enlighten me on how to use multiprocessing in this case? (few functions need to run separate Core in and executed in event-driven class?)

P.S.

The reason why I want to separate those function is while sending cumulated 100 tweets to SQS, I want to prevent the worst-case: while sending it to SQS, I might miss few valuable tweets since function send_to_sqs() is running and valuable tweet is always coming into my listener(class StreamListener).

```py
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.temp_arr = []
        self.len_temp_arr = 0

    def is_useless(self, status):
        return True if len(status.text) < 10 else False

    def update_tweet_bundle(self, new_tweet):
        self.temp_arr.append(new_tweet)
        self.len_temp_arr+=1

    def send_to_sqs(self):
        # (1)
        # send temp_Arr to SQS!
        #   inside temp_arr, there should be 100 tweets as a dictionary formats.
        print('we sent tweet bundle to SQS(ASSUME!)')

        # (2)
        # empty out the temp_arr(suppose this in Shared Memory)
        self.temp_arr = []
        self.len_temp_arr = 0

    def on_status(self, status):
        if self.is_useless(status):
            return

        description = status.user.description
        text = status.text


        table = db[settings.TABLE_NAME]

        try:
            tweet_dict = dict(
                user_description=description,
                text=text,
            )
            table.insert(tweet_dict)
            if self.len_temp_arr % 100 == 0:
                self.send_to_sqs()
            else:
                self.update_tweet_bundle(tweet_dict) # I added for multi-thread..for later..

        except ProgrammingError as err:
            print(err)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        pass

def main():

    stream_listner = StreamListner()
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listner = stream_listner)
    stream.filter(track=['yolo'])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```